# Constraint animation doesn't work Swift

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uiviewanimation

I'm trying to animate an `UIImageView`, basically in the original position the whole view is on screen. And as soon as I press a button the view should slide to the left and remain visible just a part of it. The values for the constraint.constant are:

1. On screen position = 0 (which is the starting position
2. Off screen position = -200  (which should be the arriving point)

Here's the code.

```
func constraintAnimation (duration: Double, animatedConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint, finalConstantValue: CGFloat) {

    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    UIImageView.animateWithDuration(duration, animations: {
    animatedConstraint.constant = finalConstantValue

    })
    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    println("")

}
```

Comment: I have used this before and it was just working fine, and now there is something wrong. The problem is: the view actually arrives in position but not with the right duration. Anybody knows what I'm missing..?

Comment: Do not animate the change in the constant. Animate the `layoutIfNeeded()` call.

Answer (score 4):

Change your code to this and try

```
func constraintAnimation (duration: Double, animatedConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint, finalConstantValue: CGFloat) {
     animatedConstraint.constant = finalConstantValue
    UIImageView.animateWithDuration(duration, animations: {
     self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
     })
     println("")
}
```

Comment: I've tried with your code, but still the same issue, the UIImageView moves to the left but with no animation....

Comment: I test it on my mac, it works well.Post the code about how you call this method.

Comment: UPDATE: so your code actually works. If I declare this function in the main ViewController and call it somewhere in the code  in the same file it works just fine. But what I was trying to do is to organize my project: I created a new Swift file with a new class AnimationController: UIViewController. I declared and implemeted the function there and I was trying to call it in the main ViewController. I guess the error is somewhere here. I hope this does make sense to you. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Try Writing in this manner,Below is simple example of animating a button in objective -C

```
[UIButton animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
    self.horizontalConstraint.constant+=150;
    [self.checkbut layoutIfNeeded];
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {

}];
```

your Code

```
func constraintAnimation (duration: Double, animatedConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint, finalConstantValue: CGFloat) {

UIImageView.animateWithDuration(duration, animations: {
animatedConstraint.constant = finalConstantValue//Set the constant relative to initial positon like i have didi in above example
 self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
 })
 println("")
```

}

Comment: Thank you very much, I think the problem is somewhere in the relationship between the classes. This function is declared in another swift file